# Malformed header in svn dump, not dumped revision issue

Tags: svn

Hello I have tried everything I can find online to salvage what I have left here, we had an issue where we lost our last server and the backup dump we have is having an issue with a malformed header in what seems like revision 1151. is there any way for me to recover anything from this?

I have attempted to remove the directory that seems to be the issue using svndumpfilter and get the same issue. I am unsure what I can do, I am new to running this server (only person around when it went down) and am assuming I cant just get into the dump file and remove the bad line.

svndumpfilter: E140001: Dump stream contains a malformed header (with no ':') at '?\179S?\216iw?\247Z?\205?\239?\252'XM?\197?\165?\195A;'

Answer (score 0):

you could get into the dump and remove the entire revision, that should work, but I think its probably safer to first remove every part of the dump after revision 1150 and load that in. If it gives you a repo (I think it will), then you can look at the remainder of the dump, remove the offending revision and load in all revs 1152+

You will have a hole in the repo after that, and I'm not sure what you might be able to do to recover it if your dump is corrupt.